# x86 or x64 disassembler lib

Tags: c++, c, assembly, disassembly

I know o some disassemble libs , but what I'm looking for is one that has an api like:

```
void * findAddrOfFirstInstructionStartingFrom( void * startAddress , InstructionType instruction);

void* addr = findAddrOfFirstInstructionStartingFrom(startAddress , JMP);
```

and other apis smiler to this one like search for something specific not disassemble all instructions stating from an address and get all sorts of info because it slow if you only want to find something specific not everything.

If you know any pls let me know , if there isn't any pls tell me one that is open source and easy to modify.

Answer (score 2):

You did not tag nor tell the processor architecture, so it is unlikely that you get a real answer.

Commonly native code instructions are with very varying length depending on operands they take  so you have to disassemble the thing before searching. Otherwise you just find first sequence of bytes that matches the pattern of instruction you search for. It is most likely not a real instruction but part of operands of previous instruction.

EDIT: Since you updated title, i can think of choices [Borg](http://www.caesum.com/download.php) and [PEDasm](http://reocities.com/siliconvalley/lab/6307/PEDasm.htm) are open source. If you drop that open-source thing then definitely IDA pro.

Comment: when I say    void * findAddrOfFirstInstructionStartingFrom( void * startAddress , InstructionType instruction);

void* addr = findAddrOfFirstInstructionStartingFrom(startAddress , JMP);
I don't mean search for the first sequence of bytes that match the instruction , I mean disassemble all instruction starting from that address but don't generate complicated info structure for each instruction , just keep on finding each instruction until you reached the searched one , and that maby generate info like the jmp addr for that instruction.

Comment: Disassembling does involve other difficulties too. Consider the two links i added.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any API that can do this but it can be accomplished using some command line scripting:

```
objdump -d --start-address address file | grep -m 1 instruction | cut -d : -f 1
```

So, for example, to find the first `JMP` instruction starting at address 0x08048664 in the file `a.out`, you can do this:

```
$ objdump -d --start-address 0x08048664 a.out | grep -m 1 jmp | cut -d : -f 1
 8048675
```

Comment: there is beaEngine http://www.beaengine.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10&Itemid=11  but it only supports disassembling all the instructions from a starting address with fool info suport.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is not just a library, but some Disassembler Framework. Have a look at IDA-Pro, which also provides a versatile scripting interface (and a disassembler API)

Comment: I'm looking for something free or open source and i can't find anything about IDA disassembler API

Comment: @neo_x3m: I know of no OSS counterpart to IDA – yes, having some OSS like this would be great. Anyway, here's about scripting and extending IDA: http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/idaclike.htm and http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/idaplugin.htm – now the best shot is probably what @Job told. BTW: Any such API would not work with C pointers to address parts in the disassembled binary. It would use off_t and other non pointer types, for the plain fact, that C pointers are very abstract objects and their value, if cast to an integer may be anything as long as pointer arithmetic is conserved.